# Remapping a keyboard key to print ⸮ (irony mark)

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, awesome

I find myself using the [irony mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation) ⸮ unicode U+2E2E (or ؟ unicode U+061F) in both mcabber and vim a lot. The old copy-and-paste antipattern is tedious so I thought I would rename one of the many useless keyboard keys I have to print it. So, my question is three-fold (but really the same question):

- How to do it in [mcabber](http://mcabber.com/)?
- How to do it in [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/)? Since that's the window manager I use, it should work for all application, right?
- How to do it using xmodmap or some other arcane X11 incantation?

Note that in vim this is trivial, just add `map! ;; ⸮` in your `~/.vimrc` file so in insert mode all you need is to type ";;" to get it replaced.

Comment: never knew there was an irony mark...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is in the keyboard configuration.

I don't know if you can set a custom shortcut to print the character in your jabber client, but then it would be just for that application. As for Awesome : it's a window manager, so it's not its job.

**How to input it (or any unicode character) in some (GTK at least) applications :**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then 2E2E (the hexadecimal code).

**How to configure the keyboad to get it elsewhere too :**

`xmodmap` is one way, but it's being deprecated in favor of Xkb even if Xkb configuration can look more complex. But you asked for arcane incantations :D

`setxkbmap -print` prints the keymap in use. You can send that into a file to use it as base for your new keymap. (**Skip to exemple below for the quick version of "how"**).

`xkbcomp` is an utility that can be used to compile and send a keymap to the X server.

`xkbcomp $DISPLAY keymap.dump` will dump the current configuration in the file `keymap.dump`. It's quite long as it is the same as previously, but with the values obtained from combining the `include`d elements. It can be useful to look up the names that are given to the keys. We need the name to assign another symbol to a key. You could also modify and use it directly, but you can also use the includes and just redefine what you want. The `include` are files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, in directories corresponding to the sections.

The keymap file has multiple sections :

- `xkb_keycodes`: the part that maps keyboard X keycodes to a key name used in other sections. You can get the X keycode with `xev` and find the associated name in this part.
- `xkb_types` : the part that describe types and which level correspond to which keyboard modifiers (Shift, Control, Alt, any combination of those, etc ..)
- `xkb_compatibility` : For "applications that aren't Xkb aware", from what I've read .. I'm not sure what goes here.
- `xkb_symbols`: the part that maps the key names to keysyms, and the one where we'll rewrite one of the definitions to add that unicode character. You can see the current definition of the key you want to use.
- `xkb_geometry`: the physical keyboard shape .. not sure what uses that.

If you look at key definitions in the dumped keymap, you'll see they have an associated type. The type of the key determine which modifiers are available and corresponding to which level. The combination of key and level correspond to a keysym. The type is one defined in the `xkb_types` section. 
If you don't specify another type when redefining the key, it will be the one defined in the included `xkb_symbols` map.

If I take for example my <kbd>I</kbd> key, there are four levels, corresponding to : just the key, key + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, key + <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, key + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

For the group, if you aren't using more than one layout (in your keyboard configuration), you probably have just one, and don't need to specify it. (You can use multiple groups to switch between key definitions associated with that group).

**Here is an example of modified keymap file :**

```
xkb_keymap {
 xkb_keycodes { include "evdev+aliases(azerty)"};
 xkb_types { include "complete"};
 xkb_compatibility {include "complete"};
 xkb_symbols {
  include "pc+fr+inet(evdev)"
  key <AD08> {[ i, I, U2E2E, idotless]};
  key <AD09> {[ o, O, oslash, U262F]};
 };
 xkb_geometry { include "pc(pc104)"};
};
```

With this keymap <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> gives ⸮ and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
gives ☯.

To set the keymap :
`xkbcomp mykeymap.xkb $DISPLAY`

The [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) have more details, and some other links at the end.

Comment: "azerty"... I seem to remember that from somewhere... <execute command>... Oh yeah, I remember now.  Bonjour la France! ^_~

Comment: While the lowest voted answer, this is the one I have used.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible to do in several ways. In X11 Xmodmap is probably one of the easier ways, for a simple change like this.

[Wikipedia article about Irony punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation):

> This character can be represented using the reversed question mark (⸮) found in Unicode as U+2E2E; another character approximating it is the Arabic question mark (؟), U+061F.

[Xmodmap manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xmodmap.1.xhtml):

> Keysyms matching Unicode characters may be specified as "U0020" to "U007E" and "U00A0" to "U10FFFF" for all possible Unicode characters.

I just tried, and

```
xmodmap -e "keysym F8 = U061F"
```

seems to do the trick. The command above binds that symbol on <kbd>F8</kbd> key by keysym. Of course you can bind that symbol on key of your choice. All possible keysyms (not necessarily mapped currently, though) can usually be found in files `/usr/include/X11/{keysymdef,XF86keysym}.h`. You can map it by keycode also. With tools like [xev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) you can check keycodes and their mapped keysyms on your system.

Check out some decent [xmodmap tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) on Internet.

Comment: Yes, it is that easy with xmodmap... WOW, but I do feel sheepish... I'll accept your answer tomorrow unless someone put me (even more) to shame ^_~

Comment: @Sardathrion, I hope that I didn't make you feel so. I joined Stack Exchange just couple of days ago, I'm just learning the ways here. I read your question and knew the answer (or one of the many). When I wrote the answer I just thought about making it as usable as possible for anybody.

Although I just realized that you actually gave the link to Wikipedia article, as well as Unicode values in your question... :)

Comment: ^_~ It's all good.  I knew about xmodmap, I just blank forgot about it hence feeling sheepish.  Still, this is a very nice answer.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using the Compose key system, I've just checked and it seems I've had <kbd>Compose</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> (and <kbd>Compose</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>) set to output U+2E2E for some time now (? reflected off the /)

My `.XCompose` file looks like this:

```
#
# add in the original stuff (what's usually there)
include "%L"
#
# Compose key sequences
#
# generate PI char
<Multi_key> <p> <i>     : U03C0 # U03C0 PI
<Multi_key> <P> <I>     : U03C0 # U03C0 PI
#
<Multi_key> <i> <n> <f> : U221E # U221E infinity
<Multi_key> <I> <N> <F> : U221E # U221E infinity
#
<Multi_key> </> <?>     : U2E2E # U2E2E irony punctuation (reversed ?)
<Multi_key> <?> </>     : U2E2E # U2E2E irony punctuation (reversed ?)
#
<Multi_key> <3> <*>     : U2042 # U2042 asterism
#
#
```

Here I pull in the proper 'preset' Compose keystrokes with the `include "%L"` line, then add my own customizations after that...

I've got <kbd>Capslock</kbd> remapped to be my <kbd>Compose</kbd> key, check your Window Manager how to do that, or read about the `setxkbmap` command.  But here's mine:

```
setxkbmap -model pc101 -layout us -option -option compose:caps -option shift:both_capslock
```

Sets <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to be <kbd>Compose</kbd>, also sets <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (**both**) keys to toggle Capslock. (for those *rare* occasions).  Many more `-option` options, I stripped off a couple for brevity, mainly X Windows *ZAP* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>) keystrokes and <kbd>Left-Win</kbd> being <kbd>Meta</kbd>

Comment: I like this method. No need to use deprecated xmodmap or customize XKB layout files. There are several predefined options for Multi_key mapping also:
`grep 'compose:' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`

Comment: Three things to mention: α) No need to write a custom file by yourself, you may find on github a written ones. E.g I am [using this one](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/blob/master/dotXCompose) β) Usually no need to use a terminal commands to set the Compose key, most popular environments already have it included somewhere in keyboard settings. γ) You may encounter an issue that the key doesn't work in some apps, or print a different characters for the same combination. To do it right you have to set **xim** as your input method with app `im-config`.