# Inserting the "∃" character into a text field

Tags: xbindkeys

I am trying to use xbindkeys to insert the "∃" character with a keyboard shortcut.  The following doesn't work:

`"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '∃'"
  control + shift + 3`

Instead, it sends "â".

Comment: And where do you want to "insert" this character? It is better to configure specific application (text editor, shell, whatever).

Comment: I'd like to at least be able to insert this character in emacs, vim, or in a browser search bar with the same bind.  Why is this problematic?

Comment: Why would you use `xbindkeys` instead of XCompose? This is exactly what XCompose is meant for.

Comment: Good suggestion. Could I call Xcompose from my xbindkeys configuration?  The xcompose readme isn't very clear.

Comment: Related : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134473/remapping-a-keyboard-key-to-print-irony-mark

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a fix, but at least a partial explanation: Linux uses UTF-8 encoding for Unicode characters, so the "∃" character is represented by three bytes \342\210\203. In ISO-8859-1, the byte \342 represents the character "â", and \210 and \203 represent (unprintable) control characters. It seems that there is at least one tool – xbindkeys, xvkbd, the X server, the application in which you want to insert the character, or whatever – that interprets your three-byte sequence as ISO-8859-1. That means, this tool either doesn't understand UTF-8 at all, or it is not configured to understand UTF-8 (i.e., its so-called locale is ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8). Unfortunately, I can't tell you which tool is the culprit.

Does copying and pasting the "∃" character using the mouse work, or does it fail as well?

Comment: I see.  Copying and pasting the ∃ character does work (in emacs, vim, and browser text fields).

Comment: So the application is working with UTF-8, and probably the X server as well. Perhaps there's a problem with xbindkeys or xvkbd. I'd try one of the other methods explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134473/remapping-a-keyboard-key-to-print-irony-mark